# Integrating by parts the second-order action

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, perturbation-theory

before going for the question I should state the problem:

$$S = \int d^4x\sqrt{-g} [F(\phi)R + \omega(\phi)X - V(\phi)],$$ where

$X = \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi $ is Kinetic term,

$R$ is Ricci scalar

I consider my action in the perturbed line element:

$$ds^2 = a^2(\eta)[-d\eta^2 + (\delta_{ij} + h_{ij})dx^idx^j] $$  and for the $h_{ij}$ we have these perturbed elements:

$$h_{11} = h_1(\eta, z) , h_{22} = -h_1(\eta, z), h_{12} = h_{21} = h_2(\eta,z ).$$

So I expanded my action to second order and got the following:

[image: Second order action]

And now I want to integrate my action by parts for simplicity but I don't know how to do it, I tried using Maple, but got the wrong answer, the problem is that I don't understand how to do it.

Could you please explain to me in some simple steps how to do integration by parts for this exact action of second order I got, while having partial derivatives of second order and first order?

Comment: What is $z$ and this is in 4 or 3 dimensions?

Comment: Coordinate z, so the 4-th vector is ($\eta$,x,y,z) but I consider that gravitational wave propagates along z coordinate

Comment: I'm sorry forgot to add, Yes it is 4 dimensional where $\eta$ is conformal time